# What is causing the following error using node in docker

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

I have a basic docker container that uses the latest node image.
The following is my compose yaml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    node:
        container_name: node
        restart: always
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.command
        ports: 
            - "0.0.0.0:9228:9228"
        networks:
            - domain-network
        volumes:
            - ../:/var/command

networks:
    domain-network:
        driver: bridge
```

My Dockerfile.command is:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /var/command

ENV NODE_PATH=/var/command/node_modules


EXPOSE 61337 9228

CMD ["tail", "-F", "-n0", "/etc/hosts"]
```

I've been running this configuration without any issues but today when I start it up I get the following error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9228 ./build/index.js index.js`
[nodemon] spawning
[nodemon] child pid: 244
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9228/5ba821e8-da4a-489e-87ee-74909d99946b
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
node[245]: ../src/node_env_var.cc:318:void node::EnvSetter(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `env->has_run_bootstrapping_code()' failed.
 1: 0xa62920 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa6299e  [node]
 3: 0xa6043a  [node]
 4: 0xfb7904  [node]
 5: 0x10017b6 v8::internal::Object::SetPropertyInternal(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, bool*) [node]
 6: 0x10019a2 v8::internal::Object::SetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>) [node]
 7: 0x1148e95 v8::internal::Runtime::SetObjectProperty(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::StoreOrigin, v8::Maybe<v8::internal::ShouldThrow>) [node]
 8: 0x1149f37 v8::internal::Runtime_SetKeyedProperty(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 9: 0x14c7f39  [node]
Aborted
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I even removed all the code to make sure in my index.js just to rule-out any of my code and left he barebone code below:

```
const Migration = () => {
    let log = null;

    const api = {
        };

    return api;
};

const app = RedTailMigration();
```

I run it using the following npm script:

```
"run:nodemon": "nodemon --legacy-watch --config nodemon.json",
```

and tried:

```
"run:nodemon": "nodemon --config nodemon.json",
```

I tried to Google the error but came up short.  Anybody ideas on what could be causing this?

**Update**

I tried running it outside of docker just to see if I can recreate the error and it is causing the same issue (Running on macos BigSur).  I have a feeling that nodemon is causing the problem.  I can manually run the application using:

```
node build/index.js.
```

But if I run the npm script

```
"run:nodemon": "nodemon --legacy-watch --config nodemon.json"
```

I get the error.  My nodemon.json file:

{

```
    "restartable": "rs",
    "colours": true,
    "ignore": [
        ".git",
        "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node --inspect-brk=0.0.0.0:9229 ./build/index.js"
    },
    "events": {
        "restart": "osascript -e 'display notification \"App restarted due to:\n'$FILENAME'\" with title \"nodemon\"'"
    },
    "watch": [
        "build/index.js",
        "build/commons/",
        "build/config/",
        "build/data/"
    ],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "ext": "js json"
}
```

**Update**

The error occurs when I try to debug by attaching to the instance from VSC.  As soon as I do that I get an error.  This was never an issue and only started today.

**Update**

When I run the code outside of docker and launch the debugger instead of attaching in VSC I'm able to debug the application and everything is working as it should be.  What is frustrating is that my original code was always working.  But I have encountered that when I updated to BigSur I have had countless problems with VSC.

Comment: I also changed to port 9229 but no joy

Comment: It looks like there are some important parts missing from your image – you're not `COPY`ing the application code in, and the `CMD` doesn't seem to run it.  How are you running `nodemon` here?

Comment: I create a volume share volumes:- ../:/var/command in my docker-compose file so the code is mapped in the container.  I updated my information above to include the nodemon.json file

Comment: I also tried running my code without docker just to run into the same error.  It seems like the problem is with nodemon and with I try to attach using VSC

Comment: @adviner did you ever figure this out? running into it myself. Also using VSC on Big Sur, but not using nodemon.

Comment: No, once I got it working outside of docker I didn't bother trying to figure it out anymore

Answer (score 0):

### This is an unsolved answer.

I doubt if the computer architecture matches. 
because, you just inserting node_modules.

I know docker-nodejs as a debian family architecture.
For example, if you install node_modules outside the docker on the host PC(macOS) and mount the volume, an error will occur.

Does the same phenomenon occur even if the node_modules are installed inside dokcer by modifying as follows?

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /var/command

COPY ../package*.json ./
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 61337 9228

CMD ["tail", "-F", "-n0", "/etc/hosts"]
```

Comment: I tried your idea but it still fails.  My packages are installed inside the container once it starts.  I go into the container docker container exec -it node bash and run npm install to install all the node_modules.

Comment: I have a feeling that nodemon is causing the issue.  If I run nodemond an attach using VSC is when the error occurs.  If I manually run the application using node index.js it runs without errors